# Pandas - How do I write to file, when loop is creating new columns automatically, and transpose the results?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I auto create columns after each data appending in Pandas?

**This is the result I'm looking for:**

[image]

**This is the result I get:**

[image]

Here is the code:

```
items = ['1 A','2 D','3 R','4 DS','5 OTHER']

headr = True
for item1 in items:
    headr = True
    for item2 in items:

    # appends
    df_search[(df_search['%s'%item1].notnull()) & (df_search['%s'%item2].notnull())][['%s'%item2]].count().to_csv('search_out.txt',header=headr,index=False,sep='\t',mode='a')
    headr = False
```

How do I make the result I'm looking for?